# Lion Server, Profilemanager, RVM and Rails not work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-lion, rvm, mdm, osx-server

Lion Server is absurd. On a Mac, I ran the installation and setup of Lion Server 10.7.3 then I installed rvm, Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.3.

On a Mac it worked perfectly while in the second Mac is not working and I get in the log devicemgr:

```
<Info>: default_profile_created_at_least_once was already true
Apr 10 20:23:26 <Name of Server> ProfileManager[1117] <Warning>: ** has_many_polymorphs: Warning; not all usage scenarios for polymorphic scopes are supported yet.
```

In the system log daemon devicemgr always repeated:

```
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]: DEBUG: Initializing DeviceManagerDaemon with ports 3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3329 (physmem = 8GB)
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]: DEBUG: Making sure Rails is configured properly
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]: DEBUG: Running rake command: /usr/bin/rake db:migrate
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rake (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]:   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]:   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]:   from /usr/bin/rake:18
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]: /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:109:in `rake': Rake command failed with 256 (RuntimeError)
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]:   from /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:103:in `setupRails'
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]:   from /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:33:in `run'
<Date, Time and Nome Server>.devicemanager[1634]:   from /usr/share/devicemgr/backend/devicemgrd:131
Apr 12 23:02:05 apple com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.devicemanager[1634]): Exited with code: 1
Apr 12 23:02:05 apple com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.devicemanager): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
Apr 12 23:02:07 apple xgrid[1637]: gss_init_sec_context is called on main thread, its a blocking api
Apr 12 23:02:12 apple xgrid[1641]: gss_init_sec_context is called on main thread, its a blocking api
```

How can I fix? If you want to avoid re-install everything. Thanks!

Comment: please provide more details, like what command you run, they immediate output and what version of ruby you installed and used with rvm

Answer (score 3):

I've recently upgraded to Lion Server from Snow Leopard Server, and unfortunately Apple has said in [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4042?locale=en) article that the situation that you are trying to accomplish is impossible :( and that returning to having a functioning profile manager server is nigh but impossible with the exception of rebuilding the server.

Hope that clears some things up.

-EDIT:

I managed to get the wiki server up and running again by uninstalling and deleting all of the new gems that ruby update installed. however **it is very crucial that you don't update gems if you want profile manager or wiki services** otherwise i believe everything else should work.

Shaun

Answer (score 2):

I think that (I had a similar problem) he does these steps:

- Have some service of server on like profilemanager
- Install RVM in the system.
- Install the last version of Rails.

And after these ProfileManager and, I suppose, other service go down.

Answer (score 0):

Add this information, my GEM ENV is:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.21
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/ladmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-11
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125
   - /Users/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

Profilemanager not work.

Comment: this should be part of the question, it's not an answer

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your comment. If you notice in my message explicitly write the version number to everything in the system. And those are data obtained by typing commands at the shell. The error happens when I access the page "profile manager" via the browser so I think I said all he needed, plus I added the "gem env" what else do I need?

Comment: you have put "gem env" as an answer of your question, you should edit it and put this data in the content of the question ... it helped me to debug your questions so do it for others also.